# double-ended queue array based

Tags: java, queue

I have a question regarding double-ended queue. In double-ended queue does the element at the back have reference to element at the front?

My queue size should be 50, so does that mean, i should set the back of the queue to 50-1? and front to 0?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you implementing your own?  Because, you know, there's `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: Yes my own, just wanted to know whether the back has to keep a pointer to the front.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're asking.  Is this an array-based thing?  What do you mean by "pointer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope your queue should have a pointer to the front and pointer to the back. But the the back doesn't need a pointer to the front.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement this as an array your limits are 50-1 and 0, you also need to decide if your queue should wrap around like a circular buffer.

You do need to keep track of where both ends are.